# Flask - pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

For some reason, my flask project stopped working. When I run "python run.py", my app crash. See below a screenshot of the errors in my terminal. I have checked my password and the mongoDB URI and they are both correct.

I also restarted my laptop, reinstall all the pip dependencies.

I also tried to downgrade pymongo dep.

Any help/suggestion is welcome.

[Pymongo errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2C9c.png)

Comment: it says `server selection timeout error` so you might wish to start here:   https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/server-selection-error-server-selection-timeout-current-topology/2930

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a connection to a backend component (like a mongo database) is not working, but your calling code is not surfacing the connection error.

I encountered this error in using a function from a module that was calling Mongo, but Mongo wasn't running.   When I put the code that had the mongo dependency in a try/except block and exposed the error I realized what the problem was:

```
Error: localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62c98060ffc5725d82895ab4, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused')>]>
```

I just restarted my Mongo and the error cleared.